# Angular JS Application doesn't crawl and index in Google?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have set up everything to crawl my Angular JS application in Google search engine.

`Website url :` http://templatic.net/test/

I have setup `html5Mode` for Angular JS app and also setup for generating html snapshot for particular request.

So when Google crawler will come it will get my website url like `http://templatic.net/test/?_escaped_fragment_=/job_category/mobile` for `http://templatic.net/test/job_category/mobile`

But when I go to Google Webmaster and click on `Fetch as Google` for particular link then it doesn't return my HTML snapshot for particular URL.

Also I have added `sitemap.xml` in Google Webmaster tools and it's accepted but no one single link is indexed.

I don't know what I have done wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem.I was using iis server.I solved issue by catching google crawler by checking its user agent and redirected to another server rendering application where i returns meta tags.

Here is my iis redirect rule

```
<rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="(facebookexternalhit)|(Twitterbot)|(Pinterest)|(Googlebot)|(developers.google.com)|(LinkedInBot)|(WhatsApp)" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://myredirectionapp/snapshot?qp={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
```

Comment: I'm using apache server and for catch google crawler in parameter like `_escaped_fragment_` , i have redirect it to snapshot url but i think its not working so not indexed in google

Comment: instead of checking _escaped_fragment_ check the user-agent in request

Comment: i dont know the syntax in apache.i think you can do this by finding the rewrite funtionality on apache

Comment: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot|bingbot|baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=(.*?)\/*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /snapshots/$1.html [R=301,QSD]` i have added this in `.htaccess` for apache but not working